# Where does dut in Chisel Test get defined? (About Scala syntax)

Tags: scala, chisel, chiseltest

I am trying to come up with a better title.
I am new in Chisel and Scala. Below there is a Chisel code defining and testing an module.

```
import chisel3._
import chiseltest._
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec

class DeviceUnderTest extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Input(UInt(2.W))
    val b = Input(UInt(2.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(2.W))
  })
  io.out := io.a & io.b
}

class WaveformTestWithIteration extends AnyFlatSpec with ChiselScalatestTester {
  "WaveformIteration" should "pass" in {
    test(new DeviceUnderTest)
      .withAnnotations(Seq(WriteVcdAnnotation)) ( dut => // ???
        {
          for (a <- 0 until 4; b <- 0 until 4) {
            dut.io.a.poke(a.U)
            dut.io.b.poke(b.U)
            dut.clock.step()
          }
        }
      )
  }
}
```

The code line with comments `???` is where I am quite puzzled. Where does the variable `dut` is defined? It seems an reference to instance gained by `new DeviceUnderTest`.

`test(new DeviceUnderTest).withAnnotations(Seq(WriteVcdAnnotation))`  return an `TestBuilder[T]` with `apply` method:

```
  class TestBuilder[T <: Module](...) {
    ...
    def apply(testFn: T => Unit): TestResult = {
      runTest(defaults.createDefaultTester(dutGen, finalAnnos))(testFn)
    }
    ...
  }
```

So, `dut => {...}` is a function `(T) => Unit`? But it does not look like a standard lambda (`(x:T) => {...}`)? Or it is something else?
What is this syntax in scala exactly?

Comment: It is as you have said. A `T => Unit` lambda. So, it is similar to haveing two statements `val x = test(new DeviceUnderTest).withAnnotations(Seq(WriteVcdAnnotation))` and then `x.apply(dut => {})`

Comment: @sarveshseri  We dont need to write `(dut: T)=> {}` because type can be automatically inferred according to class template T?

Comment: Yes, that is because the context knows that here a SAM Interface with `T => Unit` signature is required, so it knows that it needs either a SAM instance or a lambda with `T => Unit`. So, compiler will be able to infer that type of `dut` is `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following boiled-down version with a similar structure:

```scala
def test[A](testedThing: A)(testBody: A => Unit): Unit = testBody(testedThing)
```

What it's essentially doing is taking a value `x: A` and a function `f: A => Unit`, and applying `f` to `x` to obtain `f(x)`.

Here is how you could use it:

```
test("foo"){ x => 
  println(if x == "foo" then "Success" else "Failure")
} // Success

test("bar"){ x => 
  println(if x == "baz" then "Success" else "Failure")
} // Failure
```

In both cases, the "string under test" is simply passed to the body of the "test".

Now, you could introduce a few more steps between the creation of the value under test and the specification of the body. For example, you could create a `TestBuilder[A]`, which is essentially just a value `a` with some bells and whistles (in this case, list of "annotations" - plain strings in the following example):

```scala
type Annotation = String

case class TestOutcome(annotations: List[Annotation], successful: Boolean)

trait Test:
  def run: TestOutcome

// This simply captures the value under test of type `A`
case class TestBuilder[A](
  theThingUnderTest: A,
  annotations: List[Annotation]
):
  // Bells and whistles: adding some metadata
  def withAnnotations(moreAnnotations: List[Annotation]): TestBuilder[A] =
    TestBuilder(theThingUnderTest, annotations ++ moreAnnotations)

  // Combining the value under test with the body of the test produces the
  // actual test
  def apply(testBody: A => Unit): Test = new Test:
    def run =
      try {
        testBody(theThingUnderTest)
        TestOutcome(annotations, true)
      } catch {
        case t: Throwable => TestOutcome(annotations, false)
      }

// This constructs the thing that's being tested, and creates a TestBuilder around it
def test[A](thingUnderTest: A) = TestBuilder(thingUnderTest, Nil)

println(
  test("hello")
    .withAnnotations(List("size of hello should be 5")){ h =>
      assert(h.size == 5)
    }
    .run
)

println(
  test("hello")
    .withAnnotations(List("size of hello should be 42")){ h =>
      assert(h.size == 42)
    }
    .run
)
```

The principle remains the same: `test(a)` saves the tested value `a`, then `TestBuilder` adds some configuration, and once you add a body `{ thingUnderTest => /* assertStuff */ }` to it, you get a full `Test`, which you can then `run` to obtain some results (`TestOutcome`s, in this case). Thus, the above snippet produces

```
TestOutcome(List(size of hello should be 5),true)
TestOutcome(List(size of hello should be 42),false)
```

Comment: Thank you! The explaination is very clear. And, in the code `TestBody` does not have return value, the error message is conveyed by `assert` , is this a very common way to give the result of a test?

Comment: @Kera Basically, yes: in testing frameworks, the bodies usually communicate their "results" (if any) by throwing assertion errors. This has mostly practical reasons (you have to `catch` everything that flows from failed tests anyway, because you don't want your test-framework to crash with an exception. And it also has a nice side-effect that you can assert that "this block of code throws an exception" - i.e. exceptions are rather unexceptional from the point of view of testing frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did not notice that sometimes we can omit type declaration in lambda.

```
class tester{
  def  apply( fn: (Int) => Int):Int = fn(5)
}
```

We can write `(new tester)(x => {x+1})` instead of `(new tester)((x:Int) => {x+1})`.